# Docker-compose, How to add a new service dinamically with an API service withing it?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, openapi

I have a docker-compose file with 3 services,

1. backend
2. frontend
3. server

and I want my docker-compose file to only have backend / frontend.
My backend is a Swagger server python API and I would want to add new services to the docker-compose instance only if needed.

The goal would be for me to be able to always use
`docker-compose up --build` &
`docker-compose down`
and manage my services in between those states thanks to an API.

(Edited) I would also need to dinamically restart a server without having to restart my whole docker-compose and services

is this possible and if yes, where what should I look ? good practices ?

Comment: If you can avoid dynamically starting and stopping containers, your application will be much easier to build and test.  Also consider that, with standard Docker, the ability to start a container at all (or run Docker Compose) comes with the ability to root the entire host.  I'd look into whether you can have a simpler design that always runs all of the containers, even if they're not being used right now.

Comment: I don't want to run unused container and I may need to restart one service in my docker-compose without wanting to restart everything.